# How to make dead keys work?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on a Macbook pro with US keyboard.
I need dead keys to type accented characters in some European non English languages.  How to get them working?

The problem is the same for every application and for every user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial: [How to add and switch keyboard layout on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-20-04-desktop)

Adding the input method "English (US, intl., with dead keys)" seems to work for me.